# How would I sort a nested list by the second element in a list and then output the second lowest element in the entire list?

Tags: nested-lists

This is a HackerRank Python practice probem: [HackerRank Nested List Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem)

I am passing 8 of the 10 test cases but getting the wrong answer for 2 of them. Any advice?

Here's my submission code:

```
students = []
current_list = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        current_list = [name, score]
        students.append(current_list)

students = sorted(students, key = lambda x: x[1])

#print(students)
#print(students[1][0])

if students[2][1] == students[1][1]:
  final_list = students[1:3]
  final_list_sorted = sorted(final_list, key = lambda x: x[0])
  print(final_list_sorted[0][0])
  print(final_list_sorted[1][0])
else:
  print(students[1][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your problem here is that in regard to this part of HackerRank's problem description --

> Note: If there are multiple students with the same grade, order their
>   names alphabetically and print each name on a new line.

-- your code is assuming that "multiple" is always going to be two, whereas it could be three or more, in which case your output is not going to be correct. Another problem is that your code is also assuming that there will never be multiple students with the very lowest score.

I will also note that if you used `[score, name]` instead of `[name, score]` as your entry for each student, then `students.sort()` or `students = sorted(students)` would automatically sort in ascending order primarily by grade and secondarily by name, saving you some steps.